# opencv 3 python euclidean transformation

Tags: python, opencv, image-comparison

After calculating the matches between two images that are rotated and shifted, how do transform one image so that it can be compared to see the difference with the other image?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I have used the following to draw the matches. orb.detectAndCompute, then FlannBasedMatcher, then flann.knnMatch. I have seen the example above, but it assumes a fixed rotation of 90, etc. Given the matches how do I compute the transformation. When i use warpAffine or Perspective, it skews the output.